# Calculated column in python pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Dataframe:

```
In [19]: df_report
Out[19]: 
         Program & SKU  TPages  BOFTE
0           Sayan Lite  100000      3
1           Sayan Lite   50000      3
2           Sayan Lite   30000      4
3           Sayan Lite   20000      1
4           Sayan Lite    2175      1
5           Sayan Lite    2175      1
6           Sayan Lite    2175      1
7           Sayan Lite    2175      1
8           Sayan Lite    2176      1
9           Sayan Lite    2176      1
10  Sayan Premium Plus   20000      1
11  Sayan Premium Plus   40000      1
12  Sayan Premium Plus   60000      1
13  Sayan Premium Plus   80000      1
14  Sayan Premium Plus   40160      1
```

I have the following pivot table in pandas:

```
pt_index=['Program & SKU']
pt_values=['Tpages','Tsheets','BOFTE']

pd.pivot_table(df_report,
               index=pt_index,
               values=pt_values,
               aggfunc=[np.sum],
               margins=True)
```

it produce the following output:

```
Out[6]: 
                     sum                
                   BOFTE  Tpages Tsheets
Program & SKU                           
Sayan Lite          17.0  213054  173454
Sayan Premium Plus   5.0  240160  196835
All                 22.0  453214  370289
```

how do i create a calculated column in which the sum of BOFTE is the percentage of sum of Tpages?

the expected output:

```
Out[6]: 
                     sum                
                   BOFTE       Tpages 
Program & SKU                           
Sayan Lite          0.0000798  213054 
Sayan Premium Plus  0.0000208  240160
```

Answer (score 1):

Please provide the input dataset when asking a question.

You can do your calculation on the pivoted table:

```
df.droplevel('sum', axis=1).assign(BOFTE=df['BOFTE']/df['Tpages'])
```

or if you want a percentage, multiply by 100:

```
df.droplevel('sum', axis=1).assign(BOFTE=df['BOFTE']/df['Tpages']*100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by:

```
df['newcol'] = df['BOFTE'] / df['Tpages']
```

Comment: It will through error since the dataframe has multi index column. Also for percentage, multiplication by 100 is required otherwise its just the fraction.

Comment: the output should be 17/213054 for Sayan Lite   .

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
pd.set_option("precision", 7)   # set with precision 7

df[('sum', 'BOFTE')] = df[('sum', 'BOFTE')] / df[('sum', 'Tpages')]
```

**Result:**

```
                          sum        
                        BOFTE  Tpages
PROGRAM & SKU                        
Sayan Lite          0.0000798  213052
Sayan Premium Plus  0.0000208  240160
All                 0.0000485  453212
```

Comment: @DennisKwone  After you created the pivot table.  I assumed the name of the resulting dataframe of the pivot table is named `df`.   If you don't want to apply directly on the pivot table, you can make a copy of the table first.  e.g.  `df1 = df.copy()`.  Then, change the codes above to use `df1` instead.